# How many times is a post available to be reviewed?

Tags: support, review

I just got the review privilege, and I'm struggling to get a few to review.

As you may know I can only review "first posts" and "late answers" (which are the lowest end review tiers) at this point in time. However, most of the times these come up as 0, and in the 2 or 3 cases I've managed to see them with more than 0, by the time I read 1 question or answer as I press on whatever button is the appropriate I get hit with "There are no items for you to review."

I know this is related to this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149621/the-current-review-system-encourages-fake-reviews-some-people-upvote-everything), but I also figured, other people must be reviewing stuff too, so that's why the queue is emptying, however, how many times does a review on an item happen? once by a single user? or is it more like a rotten tomatoes approach where it get's reviewed X amount of times by different users and at the end of it if it's "fresh" it goes live, otherwise it gets declined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only the case of First Posts and Late Answers. On the other queues, for example, Suggested Edits requires enough votes for an edit to be approved or rejected before its taken out of the queue. However, because First Posts and Late Answers aren't directly tied to a type of vote, it does not work that way.